# Flowplayer, Javascript, catch click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

I have some videos in a site, which has music playing in the background.

Once I start a Video, I want the Music to stop automatically. Not a big deal when I use a javscript based HTML5 Video plugin.

However, there is a flash fallback (flowplayer). And now I have no idea how to find out (from a javascript point of view) when the flowplayer is clicked. Is there a way to catch this event via javascript? Can I somehow find out, if the div containing the flowplayer is being clicked, even though the player sits on top?

Is there a JQuery way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flowplayer features a javascript API and triggers the `onStart` event at the moment you start playing the video. You'll find more information here:
http://flowplayer.org/documentation/events/clip.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not know about this, and it does exactly what I need to do !! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can start by investigating if the `<embed>` tag or `<object>` supports `click` events. This should be possible.
You can also assign an id to the tag and trigger it from there.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630830/onmouseover-a-flash-element/4630863#4630863) might give you ideas.

Comment: I tried all kinds of events on object, but it won't do it. Flash movie is transparent, but no matter what I do, I either can't start the Video, or can't get an event ;) Thanks for your answer, though, to be honest I still wonder, why it won't work like this ;)