# How do I enable tipsy tooltips when hovering over flash objects?

Tags: flash, jquery-plugins, tipsy

I'm looking to implement a 'copy to clipboard' button exactly like github does. I'm using clippy to render the button and tipsy to get the tooltip.

Right now, there's a span of 14x14 wrapping the 14x14 flash object. However, when I apply the tipsy hover code on the surrounding span, the browser does not recognize a mouseover event because the flash object seems to grab it instead. Swapping wmode between transparent and opaque does not seem to change it.

Here is the current set up:

**HTML:**

```
<span class="clippy-wrap" title="copy to clipboard"><object id="clippy" ...></span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.clippy').tipsy();
```

What more is required for the browser to register a mouseover event on the flash object so that I can trigger the tooltip?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630830/onmouseover-a-flash-element

Comment: Ah, thanks. Also, it turns out that I had to add wmode=transparent to the <embed> as well as the <object>. That fixed the issue.

Comment: if you wanna hover your span try this $('.clippy-wrap').tipsy(); if you want to hover object $('#clippy').tipsy();